# Savon ignores namespace_identifier attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, soap, wsdl, savon

Am trying to re-write written by savon body namespace - `ins0`
I have this client variable:

```
client = Savon.client(wsdl: "https://integcert.synxis.com/interface/Contracts/ChannelConnect2004.wsdl", log_level: :debug, log: true, pretty_print_xml: true, env_namespace: :soapenv, namespaces: {"xmlns:soapenv": "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/", "xmlns:head": "http://htng.org/1.1/Header/","xmlns:ns": "http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05"}, convert_request_keys_to: :none, namespace_identifier: "ns", element_form_default: :qualified)
```

And when Am doing the request:

```
client.call(:ping, soap_header: { "head:HTNGHeader": { "head:From": { "head:Credential": { "head:userName": "******", "head:password":"*****" }}}}, message: {"ns:EchoData": "TestData"})
```

I've got this soap rq body:

```
    <soapenv:Body>
    <ins0:OTA_PingRQ>
      <ns:EchoData>TestData</ns:EchoData>
    </ins0:OTA_PingRQ>
  </soapenv:Body>
```

Where this ins0 is came from?

Also when I tried to define client with `namespace_identifier: nil` parameter and did this kind of request:

```
client.call(:ping, soap_header: { "head:HTNGHeader": { "head:From": { "head:Credential": { "head:userName": "******", "head:password":"*****" }}}}, message: {"ns:OTA_PingRQ": {"ns:EchoData": "TestData"}})
```

I've got this soap rq body:

```
 <soapenv:Body>
<OTA_PingRQ>
  <ns:OTA_PingRQ>
    <ns:EchoData>TestData</ns:EchoData>
  </ns:OTA_PingRQ>
</OTA_PingRQ>
```

And the correct body that I want to have is:

```
<soapenv:Body>   
   <ns:OTA_PingRQ>
   <ns:EchoData>TestData</ns:EchoData>
   </ns:OTA_PingRQ>
</soapenv:Body>
```

Any ideas how to remove additional nested `OTA_PingRQ`node or replace `ins0` namespace by the custom ?

Comment: Please post complete XML including SOAP:envelope. The namespace prefix ins0 must have been declared in the SOAP envelope. If ins0, ns are both defined "http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05" then the request would be valid. I would suggest to use SOAP UI to validate and test your generated SOAP requests.

Answer (score 2):

Your idea with additional namespaces was logically correct, but it doesn't look like Savon really wants to use them everywhere. It prefers to use namespaces found in WSDL. I tried `element_form_default: :qualified` and `element_form_default: :unqualified`, but it still puts `ins0` as a namespace for `OTA_PingRQ` node everytime. I thought if it wants `ins0` then let's use `ins0` then.
I looked at the list of available namespaces and found appropriate one for the header as well. Have no idea why Savon doesn't want to specify namespace for header nodes automatically, so we have to specify it manually as `ins1`.

Here is working version of configuration:

```
client = Savon.client(
  wsdl: "https://integcert.synxis.com/interface/Contracts/ChannelConnect2004.wsdl", 
  log_level: :debug, 
  log: true, 
  pretty_print_xml: true, 
  namespace_identifier: :ins0, 
  element_form_default: :qualified,
  soap_header: { 
    "ins1:HTNGHeader": { 
      "ins1:From": { 
        "ins1:Credential": { 
           "ins1:userName": "******", 
           "ins1:password":"*****" 
        }
      }
    }
  }
)

client.call(:ping, message: {"EchoData": "TestData"})
```

Request:

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ins0="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05" xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ins1="http://htng.org/1.1/Header/">
  <env:Header>
    <ins1:HTNGHeader>
      <ins1:From>
        <ins1:Credential>
          <ins1:userName>******</ins1:userName>
          <ins1:password>*****</ins1:password>
        </ins1:Credential>
      </ins1:From>
    </ins1:HTNGHeader>
  </env:Header>
  <env:Body>
    <ins0:OTA_PingRQ>
      <ins0:echoData>TestData</ins0:echoData>
    </ins0:OTA_PingRQ>
  </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

Response:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap:Body>
    <OTA_PingRS xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05" PrimaryLangID="en">
      <Errors>
        <Error Type="4" ShortText="Login failed"/>
      </Errors>
      <EchoData/>
    </OTA_PingRS>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

EDIT: Provided `soap_header` at the client configuration, because it's more efficient way.

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to attach **namespace_identifier** also.
First set namespace_identifier: nil in Savon client.

```
basic_auth = [username, password]
client = Savon.client(
    wsdl:"https://integcert.synxis.com/interface/ChannelConnect2004.wsdl",
    namespace: {},
    env_namespace: 'soapenv',
    namespace_identifier: nil,
    basic_auth: basic_auth,
    logger: Rails.logger,
    log: true,
    soap_version: 2,
    pretty_print_xml: true,
    convert_request_keys_to: :camelcase,
    namespaces: {
        'xmlns:soap' => 'http://example.com/soap-envelope',
        'xmlns:glob' => 'http://example.com/Global'
   }
)
```

Now while calling the operation set **message_tag**
response = client.call(:operation_name, message_tag: 'glob:OTA_PingRQ', message: {"EchoData": "TestData"})

Output:

```
<soapenv:Body>   
    <glob:OTA_PingRQ>
    <EchoData>TestData</ns:EchoData>
    </glob:OTA_PingRQ>
</soapenv:Body>
For Outoput like:
<soapenv:Body>   
    <ns:OTA_PingRQ>
    <ns:EchoData>TestData</ns:EchoData>
    </ns:OTA_PingRQ>
</soapenv:Body>

client call will be same but in client config add **element_form_default: :qualified**
```